# DELETE and GET have faulty behavior in a Jax-RS Restful App

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I am learning how to implement Rest API through a tutorial project.

I am facing a rather strange behavior from a routine I perform in order to test the standard CRUD methods...

Here's a general description of the code architecture:

- I am using a stub to emulate a database behavior using a static class which contains a `HashMap<Long, Message>` with `Message` being the entity I am manipulating,

  - This stub hashmap reference is in turn given to a class `MessageService` which does the logic of the CRUD method implementations,
  - The MessageService is instanciated in a class `MessageRessource` which is the Rest API containing all the `@GET, @POST, etc...` method implementations which call the `MessageService` instance methods.
- I should point out that I added 2 hardcoded entries of Messages in the `MessageService` constructor which I put in the database stub `HashMap`

Now, here's the routine which leaves me confused:

1. Run app,
2. Do a `GET` on `/messages`: Shows 2 entries,
3. Do a `POST` with custom data: Data is added,
4. Do a `GET` on `/messages`: Shows 3 entries,
5. Do a `DELETE` on `/messages/3`: Deletes 3rd entry,
6. Do a `GET` on `/messages`: Shows 2 entries,
7. Do a `DELETE` on `/messages/2`: While debugging the app, the
   `messageService` instance in `MessageRessource` has a hashmap of size 1 after the `DELETE` method is processed,
8. Do a `GET` on `/messages`: Shows 2 entries instead of 1.

My own thoughts on the problem:

- If the constructor which contains the hardcoded data was the cause of
  the problem, the `GET` method in step 4 shouldn't show 3 entries but
  only 2.
- Perhaps this has to do with the fact that no data is being returned
  by the `DELETE` while the `POST` does return the added data?

For the code, please see the GitHub public project in the [messenger App by AetosAkrivis](https://github.com/AetosAkrivis/messenger)

N.B : I know this isn't a real problem because I only need to remove the hardcoded `Message` entries in the constructor in order to be able to perform normally. But I am really curious about the reason of the malfunctioning of this routine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have assumed that the JAX-RS container will only create one instance of the service `MessageRessource`, but it can decide to clean instances or create multiple. Each time it is done the initialization, your static `messages` will be updated with 2 additional entries. Results are indeterminate

```
@Path("/messages")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MessageRessource {

    private MessageService messageService;

    public MessageRessource() {
        messageService = new MessageService();
    }
```

---

```
public MessageService() {
    messages.put(1L, new Message(1L,"Hi","Imad"));
    messages.put(2L, new Message(2L,"Hello","Badr"));
}
```

P.S: Post your code instead of linking it

Comment: So the unpredictability translates to correct POST behavior but faulty DELETE behavior (even if it is an exactly similar result each time I test)?

Comment: Also, could you please advise me on how well I can pick my code in order to put the most relevant parts without encumbering the post.

Comment: I mean that the results are indeterminate a priori. You do not know how and when the container will manage the instances. Probably with the same inputs the results are predictable. But by changing the version of JAX-RS, the application server or even the JVM could vary the behavior. It is better not to use these practices

Comment: I suggest to remove the explanation of how the code works and include an snippet of the code you are talking about: `TestResource` (just and snippet of GET, POST and DELETE), constructor of `MessageService` and the static variable. An explanation can be misunderstood, and the code usually is self-explanatory